# JUnit 4 in Android starts and process is quickly killed and no exceptions too

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, junit4, android-instrumentation

**Below is the class. As soon as the SOUT prints within a second it completes. Tested in debug mode and same.

Logcat shows that process is ended. No Exception is observed. Code compiles without any errors **

```
/**
 * Basic sample for unbundled UiAutomator.
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SdkSuppress(minSdkVersion = 18)
public class UITestPOC {

    private static final String BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE
            = "com.test.basic";

    private static final int LAUNCH_TIMEOUT = 50000;

    private static final String STRING_TO_BE_TYPED = "UiAutomator";

    private UiDevice mDevice;

    @Before
    public void startMainActivityFromHomeScreen() {
        // Initialize UiDevice instance
        System.out.println("before device init");
        Instrumentation instr = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
        mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(instr);

        // Start from the home screen
        mDevice.pressHome();
        System.out.println("after press home");

        // Wait for launcher
        final String launcherPackage = getLauncherPackageName();
        assertThat(launcherPackage, notNullValue());
        mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(launcherPackage).depth(0)), LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);

        // Launch the blueprint app
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        final Intent intent = context.getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);    // Clear out any previous instances
        context.startActivity(intent);

        // Wait for the app to appear
        mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE).depth(0)), LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);
    }


    private String getLauncherPackageName() {
        // Create launcher Intent
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

        // Use PackageManager to get the launcher package name
        PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        ResolveInfo resolveInfo = pm.resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
    }

    @Test
    public void testChangeText_sameActivity() {
        // Type text and then press the button.
        mDevice.findObject(By.res(BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE, "editTextUserInput"))
                .setText(STRING_TO_BE_TYPED);
        mDevice.findObject(By.res(BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE, "changeTextBt"))
                .click();

        // Verify the test is displayed in the Ui
        UiObject2 changedText = mDevice
                .wait(Until.findObject(By.res(BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE, "textToBeChanged")),
                        500 /* wait 500ms */);
        assertThat(changedText.getText(), is(equalTo(STRING_TO_BE_TYPED)));
    }

}
```

Debugger attached and tested but still execution fails. No exception recorded.